# Why does vue-datepicker add 4 hours to the time selected by the user

Tags: laravel, vue.js, datepicker

I'm trying to use vue-datepicker with Laravel Breeze/Vue.  But the datepicker adds 4 hours to the time selected by the user.  So, if the user selects 10:00 AM, the datepicker is returning 14:00.

I tried using a suggestion from another stackoverflow thread which uses Carbon::parse in the controller, but the problem seems to be that the vue-datepicker adds 4 hours on the frontend.

What is the best way to use vue-datepicker with Breeze/Vue?  I don't need anything with the timezone.  Whatever time the user enters, wherever they are, is what I want to store in the database.  10:00 AM should be recorded as 10:00:00, whether the user is on the East coast, West coast or anywhere else.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works this way because it reads the UTC time by default. For example, when I was trying it now, I was getting 6am since my timezone is +3. To get actual time from your date, you can convert it to locale:

```
<template>
  <VueDatePicker v-model="date" />
</template>

<script setup>
import VueDatePicker from "@vuepic/vue-datepicker";
import "@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css";
import { ref } from "vue";

const date = ref<Date | null>();

function getLocaleTime() {
  if (!date.value) return;

  return date.value.toLocaleDateString();
}
</script>
```